# Deploy GAS Web App without permission screen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, add-on

I have developed a Web App in Google Apps Script that displays data from a Google sheet. I have set view-permissions for some of my colleagues in my organization for that sheet.

If I deploy the Web App as "Execute the app as: User accessing the app" and the users open the Web App they get this screen saying that the app isnt verified ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLDoQ.png)). They need need to click on advanced etc. to grant access. For users with not much knowledge about Workspace this is very confusing and they dont know what to do with that warning and where to click.

If I deploy the Web App as "Execute the app as: Me" the users dont get a warning screen. But every user in my organization can access the Web App now, no matter if they have access to my sheets file or not (of course because the app acts as "me").

Is there a user friendly alternative to publish a Web App for specific users without having this "alert screen"?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based in the [official article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) the error seems related to the scopes that you may have defined for the app, as there may be a mismatch on the scopes used and the scopes defined. I would recommend checking that, and if the users are part of your organization. If you have admin access, I would suggest whitelisting the app in the [API controls](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227) of the Admin console. You need to add the app and mark the access as "Trusted".

Comment: In the manifest file I have only defined "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly" as scope. I have not linked a console project to my Web App. So I dont know what to change here.
Unfortunately I dont have admin access in my organization.

Comment: Any script created in Apps Script automatically creates a project in GCP. From what you have mentioned, I think the error is happening because you have not created a consent screen for your app, so you are not telling the users which scopes you are requesting when they are going to use your app, and Google understands that this is insecure. In this case you would need to set up your consent screen and make sure your project is marked as trusted in the API controls from the Admin console of your Google Workspace.